# Limiting the size of screen with css

Tags: html, css, width, screen

How would I set the minimum width of a webpage?
I thought it would be easy, turns out not...

I want to make it so that, for example, when the screen width is smaller than, say, 1000px, the content to be shown at the size as if the screen was at 1000px but with the scroll bar at the bottom (preferably with css but I can deal with Javascript).

I've read applying `min-width` to `body` would do this, but it doesn't (at least on Chrome and Safari).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Have a look at this page, it may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and set the width of the body tag if it's < 1000

https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width

Here is another trick

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-width/

Here a nice article about it.

Also try sometimes min-width doesn't work with position static if you have so many child element with absolute position.

```
 body {position: relative}
```

I hope that will help.